# How to change endianness when unmarshalling a CDR stream containing valuetype objects in Java

Tags: java, serialization, stream, corba, value-type

I've got marshaled CDR data all by itself in the form of a file (i.e., not packed in a GIOP message) which I need to unmarshal and display on the screen. I get to know what type the data is and have working code to do this successfully by the following:

```
ValueFactory myFactory = (ValueFactory)myConstructor.newInstance( objParam );
StreamableValue myObject = myFactory.init();
myObject._read( myCDRInputStream );
```

where init() calls the constructor of myObjectImpl(). and _read is the org.omg.CORBA.portable.Streamable _read(InputStream) method.

This works as long as the marshaled data is of the same endianness as the computer running my reader program, but I will need to be able to handle cases where the endianness of the data is different than the endianness of the computer running the reader. I know that endianness is in GIOP messages, which I don't have. Assuming I figure out that I need to change the endianness, how can I tell this to the stream reader?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can read the CDR stream directly like that, isn't the data already in a common format that's independant of the host endian, or is your 'myConstructor' object something you've made which is endian dependant ?

Comment: My understanding is that the corresponding _write(OutputStream) method marshals data with the endianness of the system the writing program is running on, not any default CORBA endianness (which I wish it did).

Comment: The constructor just creates a new object with all the default fields that objects of its type have. Calling _read with an InputStream populates the fields with the data in the stream. This is where endianness comes into play.

Comment: I would be highly surprised if _write cared about the host endian - which is info you can hardly get out of the JVM.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm using an x86 (little endian) machine. When I write 65535 to the output stream, I see 00 00 FF FF in the stream's byte buffer, and when I write 4,294,901,760 to the stream, I see FF FF 00 00 in the stream's byte buffer. This is like big endian. I need to get onto a big endian machine and do this to see if the byte array contents is flipped to confirm, but I think you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you access to the underlying `ByteBuffer` of your input stream, and then you can set the endianness. For example I use this to open matlab files myself

```
    File file = new File("swiss_roll_data.matlab5");
    FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
    ByteBuffer scan = channel.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY,0,channel.size());
    scan.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
```

However, I dont know if you corba framework is happy to read from a bytebuffer (corba is so 90ies). So maybe that does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the writer part I wrote in Java always writes in big endian, which might make my problem moot if I get word that the data coming in will always be created by Java programs, but I'm going to try to manually create a value in little endian format, modify my corba byte buffer's endianness to little endian, and let the CORBA _read method take a shot at correctly reading it.